# Issue linking Google spreadsheet to Google Survey forms

Tags: spreadsheet, google-forms

I have a google survey form that has no responses, I have responses in a different spreadsheet, can I link it to the new survey form?

If I try to link the form with the spreadsheet I get 0 responses, but the spreadsheet has more than 10 responses which not showing up in the survey form.
Also from the form when I click and open the spreadsheet it shows responses but the Survey form is not taking the responses to build the survey report.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the 'past' responses to the form manually (through the UI) or with program (Google Apps Script).